# How to pass warning messages from t-sql procedure?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I call the procedure in C# code. Is it possible somehow pass warning messages from the procedure to caller, like this `raiserror` calls or somehow else?

```cs
try
{
   if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open) connection.Open();

   var cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
   cmd.CommandTimeout = cfg.CmdTimeout;
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   cmd.CommandText = "dbo.test";

   var ParamReturn = cmd.Parameters.Add("@RETURN_VALUE", SqlDbType.Int);
   ParamReturn.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Test");
}
```

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE test
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    RAISERROR(N'Kuku1',0,0) WITH NOWAIT
    select @@VERSION as '@@VERSION'
    RAISERROR(N'Kuku2',0,0) WITH NOWAIT
    select @@LANGID as '@@LANGID'
    RAISERROR(N'Pisec',0,0) WITH NOWAIT
    return @@CONNECTIONS
END
GO
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read the messages (sent via `PRINT`, or `RAISERROR` with severity 10 or less) via the `InfoMessage` property of the connection:

```
using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
{
    command.CommandTimeout = 0;              
    var infoCaptureHandler = new SqlInfoMessageEventHandler((sender, args) =>
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(args.Message))
            {
                Console.WriteLineLine(args.Message);
            }
        });

    connection.InfoMessage += infoCaptureHandler;
    try
    {
        command.ExecuteReader();
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.InfoMessage -= infoCaptureHandler;
    }
}
```

Comment: `RAISERROR` with a severity of 10 or less will also fire `Infomessage` so the code in the question will also fire it. `PRINT` is severity 0.